# Visible vs Read Only?

Tags: permissions, field-level-security

Opportunity Fields > "Field Label/name" > Set Field-Level Security >

What is Visible vs Read OnLy?

A Google Search Revealed:
Visible : If you check the "Visible" checkbox, that field will be visible to that profile. **User can read & edit that field**

Read-Only: If you check the "Read-Only" checkbox, that field will be read only for the users of that profile. User can only see that field, he can't edit. **Field must be Visible to be Read-Only**

^That confuses me...

*I want The profile to only be able to **see The field; Not Edit it**. But I can't Select "Read Only" Unless I select "Visible" But "visable" allows them to edit it.*

Comment: Please try to apply tags which indicate the features your question is related to. Your question appears to have nothing to do with the `Salesforce Communities` feature, so I removed the `[community]` tag and added some that make more sense.

Answer (score 5):

The hierarchy of permissions shown in this particular facet of the Salesforce UI is a bit backwards compared to the way we usually talk about permissions. Most of the time, when talking about CRUD/FLS permissions, we understand that there are four different rights at the object level, where Read < Update < Create < Delete, and two at the field level, where Read < Edit. We also always talk about permissions as additive; we don't use the permissions system to take away rights.

In this specific context (as well as in the custom field creation wizard and the properties dialogue for fields shown on a page layout), it works the other way. "Read Only" is an extra layer on the basic "Visible"; "Visible" means Read *and* Update permission; and "Read Only" *removes* the Edit facet. This is backwards relative to the FLS editor within a user profile, although it still records the actual permissions the same way under the hood.

In your use case, you should check both boxes.

Comment: Also even if you have Visible permission , you still won't be able to edit it as that field might be locked at page layout level.

Comment: Historically, it used to be Visible and Editable, but I suspect they changed it because just because it's Editable at the profile level doesn't mean the layout can't override it. The read-only nomenclature makes it clear that you're making it read-only regardless of other conditions.